# Buttons don't seem to appear correctly if I enter number in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, input, textbox

I a slight situation here. What happens is that the user opens the grid of buttons by clicking on the (open grid link) and depending on the button selected it would display the buttons below then "Number of Answers" text box. E.g if user clicks on button "1" it displays button "A", if chose button "2" then shows buttons "A" and "B" and etc.

Now this does work until I type in a number in the "Number of Answers" textbox, then if I select a button from the open grid menu, then it would not change the buttons display below the text box.

So lets say for example there is a number in the number of answers textbox and I change the button from button "1" to button "3" from the open grid menu, then it should display buttons "A", "B" and "C" but because there is a number in the number of answers textbox it would not change the buttons below the textbox and it will still display only button "A".

Why is it doing this?

Code is in jsfiddle, click  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pSy97/10/)

Comment: Thanks for edit, did not recognise the misspelling

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pSy97/12/)

Your problem is `var letter = String.fromCharCode(i);`

You cant capture the value of input like that. You must use jQuery like that

```
    var letter = $('#numberAnswerTxt').val();
    letter = letter.String.fromCharCode(i);
```

Comment: That is ok when it comes to displaying the button but it won't let me select buttons "A", "B" , "C" etc.